# Burninate [row]

Tags: feature-request, burninate-request

From the [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/row/info):

> A horizontal line of cells in a spreadsheet, SQL table, HTML table, or similar structure.

There are 2,770 question tagged [row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/row). A representative sample of good questions:

- [jQuery: count number of rows in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149958/jquery-count-number-of-rows-in-a-table)
- [How do I add indices to MySQL tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002605/how-to-add-indexes-to-mysql-tables)
- [android listview item height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243894/android-listview-item-height)
- [CSS: Fix row height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806371/css-fix-row-height)
- [Sort rows (or columns) of a matrix in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449535/python-3-sort-rowsor-columns-of-a-matrix)

As this covers databases, data structures, and UI elements, it has far too broad a meaning for it to be of any real use.

---

FYI, there is no [column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/column) tag :)

Comment: "FYI, there is no `column` tag" -- you're damn right there isn't!  `column` is a synonym of `columns`, which is on my list of **258** tags I keep dead daily.

Comment: Agree, I don't need to know whether a database/table question contains rows or not. It comes with the territory.

Comment: row, row, row your boat...

Comment: Is it already done, or why did you accept the answer?

Comment: [`[rows]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rows) has half as many again and seems like an equivalent case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The tag has grown by a couple questions per day since May. When I first posted this answer, the latest post in the tag started out like this (verbatim from the source):

> I am trying to create a responsive html e-mail. Most of it is
> responding apart form my social media at the footer. I have one row of
> 6 different social medias. I want them to drop down to two rows with 3
> social medias per row. What is the ebst way to do this?

Yuck.

About one in five `[row]` questions over the past year have managed a positive score. Looking at [the best of them](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/370252/questions-in-the-row-tag-with-positive-scores-in-the-past-year), I don't see any where the tag seems useful. It applies to so many different contexts that if the only way I can tell a question has to do with rows is by seeing this tag, it's probably on its way to being closed/deleted.

Kill it with fire.

---

## Cleanup Tracking

I've thrown some votes in and edited a couple of recent questions that seemed to have some value (removing the tag in the process, of course) but it's a drop in the bucket given there are thousands more to go. This will probably need to be automated but before we unleash the majesty, there are [some things we should target for cleanup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/254929):

#### Orphans ✓

*[SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/370251/questions-that-would-be-orphaned-by-automated-burnination-of-the-row-tag) (current count: 1)*

- Great job!

#### Open Questions with Pending Flags

*[SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/370253/open-questions-in-the-row-tag-with-pending-flags) (current count: 3)*

- Improve borderline questions, removing the `[row]` tag in the process
- Look for opportunities to cast close votes

#### Closed Questions

*[Live search result](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brow%5D+is%3Aquestion+closed%3Ayes) (current count: 88)*

- About half of these are closed as duplicates—focus on evaluating non-dupe closed questions first, [especially "off-topic"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59054/254929)
- Look for opportunities to cast votes to delete

#### Downvoted Questions

*[Live search result](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brow%5D+is%3Aquestion+closed%3Ano+score%3A..-1) (current count: 174)*

- Keep an eye out for duplicates
- In general, treat them like First Posts – vote, edit, comment, flag, close or skip